# I am trying to execute a simple contract on Solidity Remix. But the page have different options compared to the tutorial videos?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am new to the blockchain world. So I was trying to build a simple contract using ERC20 on solidity remix. 
But the tutorials I have seen have different options when they run the same program, I am attaching you the images of both tutorials and my page.

Thanks

[image: Tutorial Image]
[image: My Image]

Comment: The remix.ethereum.org is improved and updated continuously, that causes tutorials to gets out of date. But the main elements should be in similar place. Try asking for an updated tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tech world, applications are constantly updated and improved upon and as a result, tutorials go out of date. This is why you your UI is not matching the ones in the videos.

Do not fret, Remix still has a lot of built-in tools for both auditing and analyzing your code and in general, it works nicely for developing in Solidity. You are just going to have to figure out how to locate the same tools in the current version.